# how to fix occasional return data when uploading file with ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, file-upload

I have a problem with my code. I created upload file with ajax in Laravel. I am using tutorial from here, and yes it is working. But, it working sometimes.

I have no idea where the problem is. But I have changing `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` into 0 value. I also included `<code>csrf_token()</code>` in ajax headers

I wish there somebody help me with this code. I don't know, but the code looks good for me. Here is the code

blade view

```html
 <form class="form-main"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="formbank" >
    <div class="field file" data-title="Upload File">
       <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" accept="image/*">
          <label for="myfile"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> <span id="file-title">Select File</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="field" data-title="Action">
        <button class="but-main">Submit</button>
    </div>
 </form>
```

JS script

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){

    $('#formbank').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fd = new FormData(this);
    fd.append('myfile',$('#myfile')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type:'post',
        data:fd,
        contentType: false,
            cache:false,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        },
        url: "{{ route('post.bank') }}",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);

        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});

});
```

post.bank controller

```
public function createBank(Request $request){
   if ($request->hasFile('myfile')) {

     $file = $request->file('myfile');

     return $file->getClientOriginalName();

    } 
   else {
     $text = 'empty';
     return $text;
}
```

In this case, I only try to return name of uploaded file. Here is the result.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zK5YmO8f8cGR110X-oi2bTVMiaMCXYi9/view?usp=sharing "result"

Comment: maybe it has to do with the size of the file.

Comment: i'm afraid its not. the `upload_max_filesize` is 2MB. The file is only 6,9 kB.

Comment: Try this code and check the response . `if ($request->file('myfile')->isValid()) {
    //
} `

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all suggestion. Many thanks. After several trial and errors, I find a trick to resolve it by calling main function with setTimeOut(). And i put _token validation in controller. When token is empty, it will return a value that let setTimeOut() do the rest of time until token is loaded correctly.

I guess that way is suited for me. And I will be happy if there is a better answer to resolve it in a better way. Thank you anyway..